# Why do synchronized wrappers exist for List,Set,Map when there is Collections.synchronizedCollection()

Tags: java, synchronization, decorator, synchronizedcollection

Does anyone know why should I (for example) put my **List** inside `Collections.syncrhonizedList()` instead of `Collections.synchronizedCollection()`? Do they work the same? Same applies to **Map**,**Set**.

Another thing. Why there isn't `Collections.synchronizedQueue()`?

Comment: For starters, `synchronizedCollection` returns `Collection`. So what if you wanted to do `List<Foo> list = Collections.synchronizedCollection(anotherList)`. It would not compile because the method doesn't necessarily return a list.

Comment: Oh yeah right.. But why is there is no synchronizedQueue then?

Comment: Most queues are going to need to be thread-safe to begin with. A non-thread-safe queue is not going to be very useful. So no need for a wrapper for one. The JDK does not aim to provide absolutely everything, only the most broadly useful things.

Comment: One minor observation: `Map` doesn't implement `Collection` so you can't use `Collections.synchronizedCollection()` for maps.

Comment: @Paul nice observation, true..

Comment: @Michael Actually I just checked, synchronizedCollection returns me same collection I wrapped it with. So it DOES compile I hate to tell you. It doesn't just return Collection.

Comment: //1st line: ArrayList a = new ArrayList(); //2nd line: ArrayList b = new ArrayList(Collections.synchronizedList(a));

Comment: @AnaMaria Doing that is completely pointless. You are not making use of the synchronized list at all. The 2nd new ArrayList that you create is copying all the elements of the 1st. You are not left with a thread-safe collection. You may as well call `ArrayList b = new ArrayList(a)`. The result is identical.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `synchronizedCollection()` to synchronize an `ArrayList`, the list-specific methods are not synchronized, so the more concrete method, the better. Beware that method `Collections.synchronizedList()` will synchronize all the accesses to the backed list except while iterating which still needs to be done within a synchronized block with the synchronized List instance as object's monitor. One more thing, when you create synchronized collection using `Collections.synchronizedCollection` like this :

```
Collection c = Collections.synchronizedCollection(yourCollection);
```

Then, according to documentation, the returned collection does **not pass the hashCode and equals operations through to the backing collection**, **but relies on Object's equals and hashCode methods**. This is necessary to preserve the contracts of these operations in the case that the backing collection is a set or a list.

Comment: This seems to imply that there is a danger of calling an synchronized method, and there isn't. In such a case, the list is encapsulated in the synchronized collection. The return type is `Collection`. You couldn't even cast the returned object to a List, because it isn't one.

Comment: `ArrayList` wrapped in `synchronizedCollection` has no list-specific methods, rather than list-specific methods not being synchronized. Because it's a `Collection`, not a `List`.